# vscode provide link to json schem via extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jsonschema, vscode-extensions

I need to provide a json schema for other users without using the json schema store, for example if you look at the following [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-to-a-schema-in-the-workspace) user are able to configure there own schema ,but here I want that **every one** who **installing my vs-extension** will have this **jsonschema**.

This is my question:

How should I link the user schema , for example for my internal usage what I did

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/*.tzr.json"
        ],
        "url": "./tzrschema.json"
    }
]
```

I put the schema in my workspace and link it via url and it works for me,

Assume that my `vs-ext` is providing a folder with file `tzrschema.json` , how should I **link the users
workspace** to the **file** that I’ve provided via extension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`jsonValidation` contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.jsonValidation) in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "jsonValidation": [
      {
        "fileMatch": "/*.tzr.json",
        "url": "./tzrschema.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! one question , assume that im providing a schema for files which is called `abc.json` which will be available via my extension `contribuationpoint` and in the "json-schema-store" there is another json schema for file `abc.json` , who will win ? is there a way to control the priority of schema in case there is multiple  schema for the same file name ? THanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure how conflicts like that are handled, I haven't run into a case like that. It could even just be up to extension loading order (which is undefined) or similar.